# In D&D 5e, can a fairy use lightning lure to raise an enemy into the air?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight

I'm playing a fairy wizard PC.  On my turn, could I fly 15 feet above an enemy creature and use my action to use [lightning lure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-lure)?  Assuming the enemy fails its strength saving roll, it would raise 10 feet into the air which would put it within 5 feet of me causing 1d8 lightning damage.  Then it falls 10 feet causing 1d6 bludgeoning fall damage and is prone.  Is this logical?

Lack of hovering is a concern but I'll deal with that.  My DM mentioned she would have me also do a strength roll to determine if I can maintain lift for both of us but my friendly argument is that it's magic lifting the creature and not based on my strength.  For example even if I were on the ground, my 2" 30 lbs fairy isn't going to physically pull a ~200 lbs creature but the 'magic' would cause the movement.

> **Lightning Lure:**
> Casting Time: 1 action
> Range: Self (15-foot radius)
> Duration: Instantaneous
>
> You create a lash of lightning energy that strikes at one creature of your choice that you can see within 15 feet of you. The target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pulled up to 10 feet in a straight line toward you and then take 1d8 lightning damage if it is within 5 feet of you.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it is essentially the same as that one (ie. the two spells have an identical effect). This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: But where are my manners? Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!